# why doesn't will_paginate display the items after the first page? (it's null past page 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, will-paginate

I am paginating an array `@items`

Here's the relevant controller part

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    if signed_in?
      @post = current_user.microposts.build
      @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").paginate(page: params[:page]) 
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page]) 
      @items =  (@feed_items + @activities)
      @items.sort_by! {|item| -item.created_at.to_i}
      @items = @items.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 10)
     else
    redirect_to '/signin' 
    end
  end
```

Basically, this is the line that I'm using.

```
@items = @items.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 10)
```

I also tried changing that to the code below but didn't work.

```
@items = @items.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Inside `initializers\will_paginate_array_fix.rb`
I have this line

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

In my view, I am using this

```
 <%= render partial: 'shared/item', collection: @items %>
   <%= will_paginate @items %>
```

It seems to work fine for the first page, but when I click on page 2 or 3 or others, I get a blank. It's null. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I tried it as you mentioned inside this line `@items = @items.paginate(:page => params[:page].to_i, :per_page => 10)`, but this gives me a `RangeError in StaticPagesController#home` `invalid page: 0` error

Comment: I tried this `@items = @items.paginate(:page => params[:page].to_i ||= 2, :per_page => 10)` but I get the same error

Comment: I see. I updated to this `params[:page] ||= '2'` then below that 
`@items = @items.paginate(:page => params[:page].to_i, :per_page => 10)`. What happened was that, when I opened the page, it automatically went to the 2nd page of pagination and it worked. However, after going to page 1, and clicking on 2 again, it shows null

Comment: Additionally, when I used your code, it automatically went to www.mydomain.com (no page reference) and it showed the second pagination page. It seems like `www.mydomain.com/?page=1` works but `www.mydomain.com/?page=2` shows blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are building your array by combining activities and feed items, which are already paginated and then your are paginating it again.

For example assume that your activity and feed item models are using the will paginating default which is something like 20 items per page and that there are 15 activities and 12 feed items.

On page 1 you combine this array,take the top 10 and display them. @items had 27 entries so you show links to page 2 & 3. But when you click on that you're trying to load page 2 of activities and page 2 of feed items, which are empty since there  are fewer than 20 of each.

In my experience trying to paginating through several collections like this is very tricky (unless you can load all of them and just paginate the array). A "load more items" button is easier because you just have to keep track of what the last cutoff date was

Comment: what would be an easy way to create the "load more" button? I mean the actual coding of it with the array that I have

Comment: Well you'd keep track of the last created_at date. Instead of paginating feeds/activities you would load the first 10 that were created before that date. It can be a little fiddly if you have items with the same created at date.